# What is the purpose of a single Hadoop node?

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop so this may seem like a silly question.

The purpose of Hadoop is to distribute processing power and storage across multiple computers.

So what is the purpose of a single Hadoop node? Its only one computer so there is no distribution or sharing of resources available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly learning and getting started.

Also useful for local unit testing very small workloads without touching a standing production cluster or a large dataset. For example, parsing a file, and making sure the logic works *before* you make it scalable and run into eventual issues.